# How to open new page with wordpress hook in function.php?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm am creating a new function on my WordPress theme: I want to open a new page if the options that I insert inside my form correct.

This is what i wrote inside my functions.php:

```
function form_action_filter() { 

    if($_POST['name'] == "Emanuele" && $_POST['nascita'] == "Loreto"){

        header('Location: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HBBIXeosabg');
    } else {

        echo "Compila il form";

    }

} 

add_action('myAction', 'form_action_filter');

do_action('myAction');
```

At the moment, if I write my function directly inside the layout, the function works, but, if I write my function inside functions.php when i push "Invia", the code doesn't work.

Thank's to everyone that will help me to understand how to fix this error.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Always use `exit()` after applying headers in PHP. Otherwise, the script execution is not terminated. Setting another header alone is not enough to redirect.